# Java selenium getPageSource not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need the source of the url given in the program. But the program returns oly some json data not the entire page source. What's the problem??

```
public class selenium
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    selenium.loadPage("http://photos.filmibeat.com/celebs/kajal-aggarwal/photos-c14-e13421-p592995.html");
}
public static void loadPage(String url)
{

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(url);

    String html = driver.getPageSource();

    System.out.println(html);

    driver.quit();        

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just adding more info on @alecxe answer The solution provided by alecxe is working perfectly

The console output size of eclipse is by default only 80000 characters

[image]

`Window > Preferences`, go to the `Run/Debug > Console section >` then disable `limit console option`

or write data into a file

```
    File file = new File("path/filename.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are getting the page source *too early* - *the page is not yet loaded* at that moment. Use an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait for a particular element on a page to become visible.

For instance, waiting for the photo list block to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("photoListBlock"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The above problem can be handled by both **Implicit** and **Explicit** wait. 
Here i tried with Implicit wait with your code. Please try this. It worked for me with the below code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Pagesource
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pagesource.loadPage("http://photos.filmibeat.com/celebs/kajal-aggarwal/photos-c14-e13421-p592995.html");
}
public static void loadPage(String url)
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(url);

    String html = driver.getPageSource();

    System.out.println(html);

    driver.quit();      
}
```