# Invalid HTML when using RemoteWebDriver and Internet Explorer 11 in a Windows10 environment (Selenium/Java)

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, remotewebdriver

I have developed some auto tests which works fine locally but fails using RemoteWebDriver, IE11.
The page consists of IFrames and it is only one of the frames where I can't find the elements. The other frames works fine.
I checked the HTML of that particular IFrame and found out that when running remotely the HTML was invalid (driver.getPageSource()). It misses several close tags. 
But when running locally the HTML is correct. Because of this it isn't possible to reach the elements. Does anybody have a possible solution to make the HTML be valid when using RemoteWebDriver?

It works perfect with chrome (HTML is valid using RemoteWebDriver) but unfortunately I am stuck with Internet Explorer. :(

**Prerequisite**

1. Windows 10
2. Selenium-java version: 3.141.59
3. Driver version: IEDriverServer_Win32_3.141.5

**Example: WebDriver (local)**

```
<li id="foldheader">Export Collection</li>
<ul id="foldinglist" style="display: none;">
    <li id="foldheader">EXCO Registration</li>
    <ul id="foldinglist" style="display: none;">
        <span>
            <li id="list">
                <a id="listdel" onmouseover="mOVER(this)" onmouseout="mOUT(this)" href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=D1901&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Create Collection&amp;GroupId=X4820">Create Collection</a>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span>
            <li id="list">
                <a id="listdel" onmouseover="mOVER(this)" onmouseout="mOUT(this)" href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=D2336&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Create Collection(Copy Existing)&amp;GroupId=X4820">Create Collection(Copy Existing)</a>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span>
            <li id="list">
                <a id="listdel" onmouseover="mOVER(this)" onmouseout="mOUT(this)" href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=D1929&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Acknowledgement&amp;GroupId=X4820">Acknowledgement</a>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span>
            <li id="list">
                <a id="listdel" onmouseover="mOVER(this)" onmouseout="mOUT(this)" href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=D1886&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Process MT410&amp;GroupId=X4820">Process T410</a>
            </li>
        </span>
        <span>
            <li id="list">
                <a id="listdel" onmouseover="mOVER(this)" onmouseout="mOUT(this)" href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=D3285&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Process Collection from CE&amp;GroupId=X4820">Process Collection from CE</a>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**Example: RemoteWebDriver (missing close tags)**

```
<LI id=foldheader>Export Collection
    <UL id=foldinglist style="DISPLAY: none">
        <LI id=foldheader>EXCO Registration
            <UL id=foldinglist style="DISPLAY: none">
                <SPAN>
                    <LI id=list>
                        <A onmouseover=mOVER(this) onmouseout=mOUT(this) id=listdel href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=F05030701901&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Create Collection&amp;GroupId=G49082300552">Create Collection</A>
                    </SPAN>
                    <SPAN>
                        <LI id=list>
                            <A onmouseover=mOVER(this) onmouseout=mOUT(this) id=listdel href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=F05030702336&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Create Collection(Copy Existing)&amp;GroupId=G49082300552">Create Collection(Copy Existing)</A>
                        </SPAN>
                        <SPAN>
                            <LI id=list>
                                <A onmouseover=mOVER(this) onmouseout=mOUT(this) id=listdel href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=F05030701929&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Acknowledgement&amp;GroupId=G49082300552">Acknowledgement</A>
                            </SPAN>
                            <SPAN>
                                <LI id=list>
                                    <A onmouseover=mOVER(this) onmouseout=mOUT(this) id=listdel href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=F05030701886&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Process MT410&amp;GroupId=G49082300552">Process MT410</A>
                                </SPAN>
                                <SPAN>
                                    <LI id=list>
                                        <A onmouseover=mOVER(this) onmouseout=mOUT(this) id=listdel href="javascript:mCLICK(str);" substr="ID=F05030703285&amp;Module=Export Collection&amp;Group=EXCORegistration&amp;Function=Process Collection from CE&amp;GroupId=G49082300552">Process Collection from CE</A>
                                    </SPAN>
                                </LI>
                            </UL>
                        </UL>
```

**Test source code snippet**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Driver;

public class IETest {
    private static void internetExplorerTest() {
        //WebDriver driver;
        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        URL url =null;
        try{
            url = new URL("<remote url>");
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

        //Setting the webdriver.chrome.driver property to its executable's location
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.141.5\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
        ieOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);

        //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, ieOptions);

        driver.get("<url>");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("FunctionList")));
        driver.switchTo().frame("FunctionList");

        // Check HTML in frame (Returns invalid HTML when using RemoteWebDriver. Missing close-tags)
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='Export Collection']"))).click();

        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        internetExplorerTest();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't give you the whole HTML from the IFrame due to security. But the pattern is like the above RemoteWebDriver HTML. Missing li-close-tags.

Comment: Looks like you have posted the output you got in the local IE and the output you got in the Remote web driver. I suggest you post your selenium code and the HTML code from that Iframe. It can help us to make a test with it and check for the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT 
Thank you for your answer. I added some test code but unfortunately I can't upload the whole HTML due to security.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that you are printing the output in the console.

You are getting the output but it is incomplete.

It can be possible that the source is large but the **console buffer size** is less. Due to this reason, this issue may occur.

If you are using the Eclipse then you can refer steps below to increase the **console buffer size**.

1. Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
2. Increase the Console buffer size
3. OR simply uncheck “Limit Console Output” all together

[image]

Another workaround is to write the data into a file.

```
File file = new File("path/filename.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(content);
bw.close();
```

Reference:

[Java selenium getPageSource not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307541/java-selenium-getpagesource-not-working)

You can try to check it on your side and let us know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: I actually did that before. Unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Did you try saving the source in a file? What result did you get with that test?

Comment: I got the same result. The source had missing end tags when executing RemoteWebdriver. But if executed local (WebDriver) the HTML was valid without missing end tags.

Comment: Are you trying to access the same web page on your local and using a remote web driver? If it is a public page then you can try to share the link here. We can try to test it with the Remote web driver to check the results.